# Substitute for u'string'

Tags: python, utf-8

I saved my script in UTF-8 encoding.

I changed my codepage on windows to 65001.

I'm on python 2.6

Script #1

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
print u'Español'
x = raw_input()
```

Script #2

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
a = 'Español'
a.encode('utf8')
print a
x = raw_input()
```

Script #1, prints the word fine with no errors, Script #2 does error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec
>   can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 4:
>   ordinal not in range(128)

I want to be able to print this variable without errors dynamically as in script #2.
the encode('utf8') was mentioned to me as the equivalent of doing u'string'

Obviously, it's not because it throws errors.
How can I do it folks?

Comment: Is it because you didn't prepend the string with `u`? I'm used to Python 3.

Comment: Yes, I purposely didn't prepend the u.
I was trying to prove a point of how the same thing can be done on a dynamic variable, like if you were reading strings from a file for example.

Comment: (in Python 2x) `u'...'` is a real unicode string (encodingless), if you want to convert from ordinary string, you have to know its encoding, the conversion process from it to the unicode string is decoding. encoding is used for `u'...'` -> `'...'` (and you have to tell the desired result encoding)

Answer (score 8):

Change your code to the following:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
a = 'Español'
a = a.decode('utf8')
print a
x = raw_input()
```

Decode specifies how the string should be *read*, and returns the value. Making the changes above should fix your problem.

The problem is that python stores a string as a list of bytes, regardless of the encoding of the file. What matters is how those bytes are *read*, and that is what we are doing when we use `decode()` and `u''`.

Answer (score 5):

For script #2:

```
a = 'Español'           # In Python2 this is a string of bytes
a = a.decode('utf-8')   # This converts it to a unicode string
print(a)
```